# get check out cart attributes using magento

Tags: magento

I was successfully getting the all the cart details(i.e total items, items in the cart, etc).

But i want only specific attributes from cart.
suppose i want to get **store_id** attribute, how can i achieve.

```
public function info($quoteId, $store = null)
    {
        $quote = $this->_getQuote($quoteId, $store);
        $result_attr = $this->_getAttributes($quote, 'quote');
       //this is giving error
        $result_attr->getAttributeText('store_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting object in your `$quote`

you can get with below code

```
if($quote )
    $store = $quote->getStoreId();
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @user2629419,glad to help you. will please vote up my answer so some one can trust on it and use for future help.